# How to display an overlay on my Android GoogleMap (V2) above road level ?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have my own offline map data in my app but only for a small region. Now I'd like to overlay this data onto my Google Map V2. This also already works. The only thing missing now is that `GoogleMaps` still overlays it's road names / city names above my tiles.

Is it possible to display a google map V2 in Android with `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL` and overlay custom tiles above roads?

```
TileOverlay overlay = map.addTileOverlay(new
TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(provider).zIndex(2000));
```

The zIndex does't seem to help me here.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you're trying to achieve ? maybe a screenshot would be usefull. About zIndex why did you set 2000 and not something else like 9999 ? is it the highest value for Z ?

Comment: The Ground Overlays demo works exactly as you describe.  The tile overlay doesn't show anything below it but I think its map type none.

Comment: You can have see screenshot of my problem here: http://goo.gl/vD3Nb4
I want the Labels drawn on top gone (the one's that aren't blurry in the screenshot :) )
MAP_TYPE_NONE is not an option... I want to see the map if online in regions I don't have tiles for...

Comment: Is there a possibility to alter the map styles? You could a styler to a feature saying `{ visibility: 'off' }`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way to display your tile-layer over the road names/city names.

How about display your offline map as Marker?
It should be displayed on the top.

Comment: I guess markers are not intended to display MapTiles?!? Zooming in and out of the map would lead to weird effects I guess....

But do you have any link to show me how this could be archived?

Answer (score 1):

try [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay) link for **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay** &

EXAMPLE :

```
GoogleMap map; // ... get a map.
TileProvider tileProvider; // ... create a tile provider.
 TileOverlay tileOverlay = map.addTileOverlay(
 new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing... but then my tiles are on top of the Google-Tiles but underneath the Google-Map Labeles.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot place TileOverlays or GroundOverlays on top of labels. Your best option might be to use a different map type. This can be changed after the map has been created (i.e. in the `onMapReady` method by using the [`mMap.setMapType(...)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-final-void-setmaptype-int-type) method). Here are some possibilities:

### `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL` + Custom Map Style

You can easily create your own map styles by using the [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). It allows you to create a style that excludes labels entirely (among other things). Once you've created a style you like, you can copy the JSON code generated by that website and add it to the project file `res/raw/style_json.json`. The style can then be applied like this:

```
mMap.setMapType( GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL );

try
{
    boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
            MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                    getContext(), R.raw.style_json ) );

    if( !success )
    {
        Log.e( TAG, "Style parsing failed." );
    }
}
catch( Resources.NotFoundException e )
{
    Log.e( TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e );
}
```

### `MAP_TYPE_NONE` + Custom Map Tiles

If you **need** to have labels outside of your TileOverlay, you could add a second TileOverlay of non-Google map tiles (like those provided by [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about)). These typically include the labels within the map tiles themselves. So if your TileOverlay is added with a higher [z-index](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#z-index), it will appear on top of these other map tiles!

### Map Types Without Labels

`MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE` and `MAP_TYPE_NONE` don't include labels. If you don't need **any** map data outside of your TileOverlay, using `MAP_TYPE_NONE` will save on mobile data.